# Minutes of Meeting - Setting up excel to handle MoM

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, email-attachments, spell-checking

TL;DR in bottom

I have all ways dreaded the tedious task of writing/proofing and distributing MoM and I have therefore always tried to stay clear of this task… but sadly not anymore.

I’m therefore now trying a new approach to ease this task and would like some help with achieving that and hopefully share it with all of you when I finish. Below you will see a small list explaining what I would like to end up with.

- I decent looking format, as of now the template for the MoM is a word document setup by two twelve-year-old kids using comic sans. With my none-exciting design skills, I now have created the attached setup.
- On a different sheet (input) I have created a list of names for the participants, in the cells the right of that I have their email and to the left I have a “check box” cell, where a “x” will indicate that said person is present at the meeting.
- Furthermore I have setup two different macro’s:

  **"Forward Draft"**
- Create a new excel file only containing the “MoM Sheet”, naming it appropriately (MoM_ProjectName_Data) and forward it to my supervisor who then will be able to proofread and edit it.

  **"Publish"**
- Create a .pdf file of the “MoM Sheet”, save it to the same folder as the excel file is located, and send it to the email addresses on the input sheet.

**And now all my issues:**

Starting with the design of the “MoM sheet”

- How to handle a page break? I would like the frame to be repeated on the following pages, so that the format isn’t changed.
- Including spellchecking

  **"Forward draft Macro"**
- What really bugs me is that I have to forward an editable edition
  to supervisor. I have been back and forth between just forwarding the
  entire file as it is – to export the text to word and send that file.
  All inputs on this matter will be highly appreciated as this is where
  I’m super stuck atm.

  **"Publish Macro"**
- This should be dealt with but as a bonus feature, it would be awesome
  if the macro would save the pdf file directly in a SharePoint
  location. The entire organization is using SharePoint to handle all
  project documents.

[image: Picture of the design]

TL;DR: Inputs on how to manage MoM drafted in Excel: Forward a copy for review, Create a design that handles pagebreaks, upload directly to sharepoint